# PHPExcel Chart deleted by Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I'm trying to make a chart on Excel file via PHPExcel..

I can make the table for the `datasource` for the chart.. Look like this

[image]

and I've write code for the chart.. Look like this..

```
$values = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$1:$B$11', NULL, 11);
$categories = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$1:$A$11', NULL, 11);
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,        // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,    // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($values)-1),                      // plotOrder
    array(),                                         // plotLabel
    array($categories),                                // plotCategory
    array($values)                                // plotValues
);
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL,false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',           // name
    $title,             // title
    $legend,            // legend
    $plotarea,          // plotArea
    true,               // plotVisibleOnly
    0,                  // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,               // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel         // yAxisLabel
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->addChart($chart);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel); 
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);

header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="aOSalesPerformance.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

And this is the error that excel give me when I'm trying to open the document that generated by that code

[image]

Why this error came ? Why Excel say Drawing Shape has been Removed ?
Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason you received that error is because you over-selected the plot values and included the header. For example with these two lines the range should start at A2 and B2, since A1 and B1 contain the header and NOT values you want plotted.

So these two lines:

```
$values = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$1:$B$11', NULL, 11);
$categories = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$1:$A$11', NULL, 11);
```

Should be:

```
$values = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$11', NULL, 11);
$categories = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$11', NULL, 11);
```

That will take care of the error, but your chart will still not be displayed since you also need to specify a location for said chart to be displayed. So these two extra lines will also need to be added:

```
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A20');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('L50');
```

That will take care of the error you are receiving and the lack of displayed graph. However I would recommend creating the array for $values and $categories outside of creating the $series object as that would allow for plotting more than just one column of data. [This website has a good tutorial on creating charts using PHPExcel](https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/)

Corrected code below:

```
$values = array();
$values[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$11', NULL, 11);
$categories = array();
$categories[] = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$11', NULL, 11);
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,        // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,    // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($values)-1),                      // plotOrder
    null,                                         // plotLabel
    $categories,                                // plotCategory
    $values                               // plotValues
);
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL,false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
$k="y axis";
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',           // name
    $title,             // title
    $legend,            // legend
    $plotarea,          // plotArea
    true,               // plotVisibleOnly
    0,                  // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,               // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel         // yAxisLabel
);

//Location where chart will be displayed
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A20');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('L50'); 

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->addChart($chart);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="aOSalesPerformance.xlsx"');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```